# Using PayPal Webhooks with Parse.com CloudCode

Tags: url, parse-platform, paypal, http-headers, webhooks

Is it possible to configure PayPal Webhooks so they will trigger CloudCode functions in Parse.com? There is no any place to specify Parse Headers, as X-Parse-Application-Id and X-Parse-Client-Key, just a plain URL available. So I wonder how can I trigger the cloud code function from PayPal webhook.
Or should I use some kind of a PHP file just to retrieve the webhook and the call cloud code function from it?

Comment: You've answered your own question...

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are two ways to manage this.
1. You can make an Express.js app and deploy it to parse. This is how I did.
So you need to simply visit the URL, for example

```
app.post('/paypal-callback', function(req, res) {
```

Make sure you're hosted your app with Parse. Find "Hosting" in "Settings", it should be like: app.parseapp.com.
2. Use the following format:

```
https://myAppID:javascript-key=myJavaScriptKey@api.parse.com/1/functions/myCloudFunction
```

Didn't check it myself, but one of the Parse engineers was talking about that.